# Do whirlybirds rotate from an internal air current?

Tags: cooling, ventilation

I understand that whirlybirds are designed to spin with the wind creating a vacuum inside and hence draw out air in a roof space. What I'm curious about is whether an air current from inside a roof space could cause the same effect. For example, if you mounted a fan under a whirlybird (pushing air into the centre of it) would it spin?

Comment: Not familiar with the term whirlybird.  Does it refer to an [attic fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attic_fan)?

Comment: In Australia that would be the "Wind-powered roof turbine ventilator" in your link.

Answer (score 0):

The typical wind-powered extractor fan will spin if air is pushed in from underneath, and you can see this in action on hot, still days when hot air is moving from the attic space into the open air. But they typically spin quite slowly, and sometimes not at all (if there is a row of them often not all are lazily rotating).

[image: diagram showing internals of wind-powered roof turbine ventilator]

The construction is shown above, basically a turbine that you can see powering a fan with box fixed to the same shaft.

If you wanted to motorise one it would be much more effective to power the shaft directly, thus eliminating two sets of [propellor losses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propeller_(aeronautics)) which may be as little as 10% but more likely over 50%. In other words, a 5W motor on the shaft is likely to spin the whirlybird as effectively as a 50W fan pointed vaguely towards it. And you could power the 5W motor from a small solar panel...  https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=solar+powered+whirlybird there are many DIY projects and products for sale that do just that.